# Hyper-V Scenario

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I am planning to create a hyper-v environment for testing, I need to have something similar to the following:

Group 1

DC 1
WSUS 1
App Server 1
AV Server 1
Client xp 1
client 7 1

Group 2

DC 2
WSUS 2
App Server 2
AV Server 2
Client xp 2
client 7 2

Group 3

DC 3
WSUS 3
App Server 3
AV Server 3
Client xp 3
client 7 3

When I need to use it it will run by group , no need to run 2 computer groups at the same time.

can this be done, and if I have a resources that will run a single group only can it be used to do the set up above, since they will not run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks feasible and you've thought through naming conventions which is where things could go wrong otherwise.  You'll need to consider the DCs in a couple of scenarios:

1. Do you intend the DCs to belong to the same domain, and is this domain going to be the same as your host uses?  This would really simplify your scenario, you would simply ensure that in each group the servers and clients have each groups DC IP addess as their preferred DNS server.
2. If you're having each of your DCs govern different domains on which a groups servers and clients reside then this gets trickier, you would need to create a trust between each one and your host domain.

Bear in mind that WSUS usually takes a day or two to start working and updating, so you might want to consider that within your test scenario.  I can't see any reason why your scenario wouldn't work.  As long as you have the disk resources to contain 18 servers/clients as VMs and enough RAM and CPU to fire up 6 at a time.

Comment: Thanks Mark, each group will have its domain, but I am thinking of have a parent DC on another physical machine, and in each group will be a sub domain, i think this is better

Comment: Unless I know what your goal is in having test servers and clients grouped with a DC I can't comment.  Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Sure, i will use them to test some application and patch and software distribution, there will be also configuration mgmt .                    but the group because i have different sets of images for users who use diiferent config and apps, what do you think

Comment: Without trying to needlessly oversimplify, could you use one domain and run different GPO policies for each group of users?  From what you've described I don't see a reason for different domains - unless you are doing a security proof of concept for a large enterprise.

Comment: you are right for the domain, but the main thing here Mark as you said it can be done, so i can configure all the machine in the design i want then I can power it group by group ?

Comment: Yes, I don't see a problem with that.  If I was doing it I would makes sure that I had a physical NIC per domain group (i.e. x3) and create a virtual switch on each, so that when you are running different groups, they are on different subnets.  Otherwise, you might get overlapping DNS records and various levels of confusion, especially if you fire up a DC accidentally.